# Can not query more than 1000 entities from datastore from my java application in google appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I have a java8 appengine project and I need to query the datastore to get all the entities. But there is a limitation that I can only query 1000 entities at a time. My application need is that i need to get all the entities at once. I can not find any suitable way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to issue follow-up queries that pass a startCursor by using the endCursor from the previous query run (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/samples/datastore-cursor-paging#datastore_cursor_paging-java).